# UIButton creating error - "unrecognized selector sent to instance"

Tags: swift, uibutton

I have added a button to my view using this code, however it comes up with the error "unrecognized selector sent to instance" and crashes the app.

Does anyone know why this is ?

Many thanks!

```
       let button: UIButton = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(100, 400, 100, 50))
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        button.setTitle("go Back", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action:  "buttonAction:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        self.view.addSubview(button)


    }

    func buttonAction(sender: UIButton!) {

        println("SegueSTGB")
        performSegueWithIdentifier("SegueSTGB", sender: self)

    }
```

Comment: Show (paste in) the _actual exact_ error message and say _when_ it happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should modify addTarget:

```
button.addTarget(self, action:Selector("buttonAction:"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
```